# Marker not adding to my map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Trying to add a marker to a google map on a contact page I've created. Map renders fine but marker does not appear. Heres my code:

```
function initialize() {
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-43.51187,172.621192);
                    var myOptions = {
                      zoom: 15,
                      center: latlng,
                      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                    myOptions);
                    NSMarker();
                }

                // Function for adding a marker to the page.
                function addMarker(location) {
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: location,
                        map: map
                    });
                }

                // Add Marker Location
                function NSMarker() {
                    NSArchitects = new google.maps.LatLng(-43.51187,172.621192);
                    addMarker(NSArchitects);
                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

declare `var map` outside of initialize() function

```
var map; // declare globel

function initialize() {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-43.51187,172.621192);
    var myOptions = {
          zoom: 15,
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);
    NSMarker();

}

function addMarker(location) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: location,
                    map: map
                });
            }

            // Add Marker Location
            function NSMarker() {
                NSArchitects = new google.maps.LatLng(-43.51187,172.621192);
                addMarker(NSArchitects);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew I'd have a duh moment as soon as I saw the answer.